# JS page scroll didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote code something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: form.attr('action'),
  data: data,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(html){
    $(html).hide().appendTo(parent.find("[data-interactions]")).show().stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(".vote_feedback_snippet:last-child").offset().top
    }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
```

I above code when I click on post button it generates new HTML snippet at the bottom of the list
**What I want:-**
When new Html Snippet come it will scroll upto that snippet only

Can somebody help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(html).hide()
.appendTo(parent.find("[data-interactions]"))
.show('fast', function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop:  $(".vote_feedback_snippet:last-child").offset().top
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 on this answer for using the callback mechanism to sequence events.

Answer (score 0):

Using this plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

will allow you to do this:

```
$.scrollTo(".vote_feedback_snippet:last-child")
```

It's always worked for me.